# List of List, Data Analyzed Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I Converted a csv to list:

```
import csv
with open('DataAnalizada.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(reader)
```

I need to analyze the information on that list where it is analyzed by customer groups and dates first as AAA customer on 12/27/2017, AAA on 12/28/2017, BBB on 12/27/2017, BBB on 28 / 12/2017, CCC on 12/27/2017, CCC on 12/28/2017 and within each of these groups the Analysis is taken into account (Stable Alert or Increment, which are the 3 variables that can be presented) in this case if for the AAA client on 12/27/2017 all the Analysis values ​​were Stable, I want the new csv file to appear: AAA, 12/27/2017, The client's performance was Stable and so on for each client and date!

I need some function that is conditional where for each list that the client and the date are equal analyze the column of Analisis and according to this if they are all Estable, AAA, 12/27/2017, Estable: The client's performance was Estable and if no AAA, 12/27/2017, No Analized

I'm fairly new to python and I can not do it on my own sincerely. I do not know how to go through a nested list and group it as I ask earlier. My apologies for the lack of code in the question

```
a = [['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Variables', 'Dia Previo', 'Mayor/Menor', 'Dia a Analizar', 'Analisis'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Alerta'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Alerta'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '27/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable'],
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '0.41', 'Dentro del Margen', '0.35', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '2.25', 'Dentro del Margen', '2.7', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '62.4', 'Dentro del Margen', '61.21', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '153927.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '173663.0', 'Estable'], 
['AAA', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '6827946.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '6431093.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'ECPM_medio', '1.06', 'Dentro del Margen', '1.06', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Fill_rate', '26.67', 'Dentro del Margen', '27.2', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Importe_a_pagar_a_medio', '11.34', 'Dentro del Margen', '12.77', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Impresiones_exchange', '10648.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '12099.0', 'Estable'], 
['BBB', '28/12/2017', 'Subastas', '39930.0', 'Dentro del Margen', '44479.0', 'Estable']]
```

An example of the New csv I need:

```
Cliente,Fecha,Analisis
AAA,27/12/2017,Stable: The client's performance was Stable
AAA,28/12/2017,Stable: The client's performance was Stable
BBB,27/12/2017,Stable: The client's performance was Stable
BBB,28/12/2017, Stable: The client's performance was Stable
CCC,27/12/2017,Stable: The client's performance was Stable
CCC,28/12/2017,Stable: The client's performance was Stable
```

Comment: Could you post a sample output how do you want? Why not `pandas` for these types of analysis?

Comment: I just put one! @i.n.n.m

Comment: For my naked eye, from your sample data everything should be stable because BBB also appears in both dates. otherwise, `BBB,28/12/2017,No Analized` under what condition? Also, lets delete some comments above to keep it clean

Comment: My apologies I edited the list but it didn’t save! Yes you are write! Now we are in the same way! Do you understand my question now? @i.n.n.m

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might lead you to what you want, however, not sure this will be totally helpful. Since you don't have a condition to filter data, I tried the following way to just get your desired output. Note, this is just a try to guide you towards pandas.

`pandas` would be the best way to go about this as you could manipulate the data, the way you want. To read csv in [pandas](http://pythonhow.com/data-analysis-with-python-pandas/).

I just did like this to get your data into pandas data frame,

```
import pandas as pd
headers = a.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = headers)
df
```

output:

```
   Cliente  Fecha      Variables  Dia Previo    Mayor/Menor        Dia a Analizar   Analisis
0   AAA     27/12/2017  ECPM_medio  0.41        Dentro del Margen   0.35    Estable
1   AAA     27/12/2017  Fill_rate   2.25        Dentro del Margen   2.7     Estable
...
```

After this, I created a new column with status (Still don't know the exact condition)

```
for i in df['Analisis']:
    if i == 'Estable' or i == 'Alerta':
        df['Status'] = 'Stable: The client''s performance was Stable'
```

Now, you can use `groupby` function in pandas to create your desired output.

```
df1= df.groupby(['Cliente','Fecha', 'Status']).size()
df1
```

output,

```
Cliente  Fecha       Status                                    
AAA      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
         28/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
BBB      27/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
         28/12/2017  Stable: The clients performance was Stable    5
```

When you use `groupby` you have to use an aggregate function, I used `.size()`.

Now, you can write this dataframe df1 into csv. You can always wrap these into a function also. Hope this will lead you to an efficient method of analysis for your purposes.

Comment: It's okey but I have a problem. If a have "down" in the Analysis column I have the same results Stable: The clients performance was Stable. How can it possible?

Comment: The exact condition is if any column of for example `Cliente AAA` have all your `Analisis`column `Estable`,  `df['Status'] = 'Stable: The client''s performance was Stable'`if not `df['Status'] = 'NotAnalyzed'

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv 
from collections import namedtuple

with open('DataAnalizada.csv', 'rb') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    first_col = reader.next()
    header = namedtuple('header', first_col)
    data = {}
    for val in reader:
         get_ = header(*val)
         if get_.Analisis == 'Estable':
             get_data = (get_.Cliente, get_.Fecha)
             if get_data in data:
                 get_list = data[get_data]
                 get_list.append(val)
             else:
                  data.setdefault(get_data, [])            
    with open('DataAnalizada_new.csv', 'wb+') as filename:
        header = ['Cliente','Fecha','Analisis']
        writer = csv.writer(filename)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for val in data.keys():
            writer.writerow(val + ["Stable: The client's performance was Stable"])
```

Comment: i hope it may help you now..!

Answer (score -1):

The Pandas package has the tools you need.  However I  would  recommend starting with [scipy](https://www.scipy.org/about.html) and [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux) since I found installing Pandas on its own to be quite difficult.

Comment: You need to provide an answer and not your oppinion on what tools you consider be used.